# HTML Parsing using Jsoup library

Tags: java, android

```
<div class="serieSelector serieSelected" data-serie="36" data-title="Steps">
    <div class="value fontGreyBold">2620</div>
    <div id="stepsPulse" class="fontGreyLight">Steps</div>
</div>
```

I am currently working on an Android project which needs to parse some data from the website and display the data in TextView's. As seen above, I need to display the value Highlighted which is "2620". I'm using Jsoup and that is my Element data obtained from the website. I dunno what tag to use exactly.

```
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements stepstaken = document
                .select("div[class=measureValue fontGreyBold]span[class]");
        stta = stepstaken.attr("class");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above code doesn't work so any possible replies are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please format your code :)

Answer (score 0):

I always just use **[PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)** whenever I need to parse anything. Then you'd just create a simple REST API that returns the parsed results. Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this seclector

```
document.select("div.value.fontGreyBold");
```

Example

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<div class=\"serieSelector serieSelected\" data-serie=\"36\" data-title=\"Steps\">"
                + "<div class=\"value fontGreyBold\">2620</div>"
                + "<div id=\"stepsPulse\" class=\"fontGreyLight\">Steps</div>"
                + "</div>";

        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements stepstaken = document.select("div.value.fontGreyBold");
        System.out.println(stepstaken.text());
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. I think there may be a problem with the login. This page requires a login and maybe the class is not recognizing the logged in session.

Comment: You can use jsoup to issue the login request first and then parse the response.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I'll try it that way and keep you updated.